# Deploying a webapp to a websphere application server that checks the health of the host server

Tags: java, rest, url, web-applications, websphere

If i have a webapp deployed to a specific server or host, and this webapp checks the health of the local server its deployed on when you call a get request on its URI.

The problem I am having is that if the server goes down, you can't even make a get request to the health webapp (webapp simply uses a URL object with the localhost and port path and gets the connection code).

Would creating a seperate JVM for the webapp solve this problem? or does the webapp need to be hosted entirely on another server?

i'm a beginner so have mercy.

Comment: What version of WebSphere are you using? Full-blown WAS or Liberty? If it's regular WAS, is it Base or Network Deployment?  Your available options change quite a bit depending on the specifics.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is not feasible. you will need a third party vendor app to check your server from outside the host itself. i can give you many suggestion. but just try these first, datadog apm and nagios.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's totally reasonable to use a small JSP for a health check of the server itself.

If you can't reach the JSP, it's a pretty extreme case of the server being in trouble.
If you can reach the JSP, you can query some mbeans to summarize a more detailed/nuance health.